If $τ$ is independent of $(\mathcal F_t)$, how can I enlarge $(\mathcal F_t)$ to $(\mathcal G_t)$ so that $\tau$ is an $(\mathcal G_t)$-stopping time?
Let

$(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space;
$I\subseteq\overline{\mathbb R}$;
$(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in I}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$;
$(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space;
$(X_t)_{t\in I}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in I}$-adapted process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$;
$\tau$ be an $I$-valued random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ independent of $$\mathcal F_\infty:=\bigvee_{t\in I}\mathcal F_t.$$

Note that if $\tau$ would be an $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in I}$-stopping time, then $$\operatorname P\left[\tau\le t\right]=\operatorname P\left[\tau\le t\right]^2\in\{0,1\}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I\tag1;$$ i.e. $\tau$ would be almost surely constant.
Question: What is the smallest filtration $(\mathcal G_t)_{t\in I}$ with $$\mathcal F_t\subseteq\mathcal G_t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I\tag2$$ for which $\tau$ is an $(\mathcal G_t)_{t\in I}$-stopping time?
My guess is $$\mathcal G_t:=\mathcal F_t\vee\sigma\left(\bigcup_{\substack{s\in I\\s\le t}}\{\tau\le s\}\right)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in I,$$ but I wonder whether I'm missing something here.
